# IntelliJ Default System Encoding

Tags: windows, encoding, intellij-idea

I have problems with IntelliJ because it detects default system encoding like cp-1252 and then it uses that preference for my projects. 
Where does IntelliJ gets that information from and is there any way how to change that default system encoding?

This applies for IntelliJ 14 and windows 7.

Comment: Moderator: Ignore my flag to migrate this to SuperUser.  OP asked in the appropriate place, I just misunderstood.  Sorry for making this a comment, but I didn't see another place to put it, and there is no un-flag functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to:

`File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Editor -> File Encodings`

There you can change the default encoding that IntelliJ will use. 
To change the settings for a specific project go to:

`File -> Settings -> Default Settings -> Editor -> File Encodings`

[CP-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is the default windows encoding for characters in the Latin alphabet.